# Chrome on macOS suddenly rejects self signed certificates

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keychain, ssl

I have been happily using self signed certificates for locally hosted sites running on apache2 for a couple of years.  Today *one* of those certificates expired - no biggie, I recreated it and replaced the cert in my keychain.  However, Chrome is now giving me an error when I try to visit the site:

> Certificate Error
>   There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).

So I thought maybe the cert I had generated was dodgy.  But no - all of my other (unexpired) self signed certs have stopped working too!  Is it a coincidence?  I don't know.

I thought maybe it didn't like my 'common name' (which was `com06`, e.g. `https://com06/`) so I tried with `com06.dev`.  No luck!

What is going on?

Certs generated with

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.crt
```

Added to keychain with

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain server.crt
```

- macOS 10.11.6
- Chrome v58.0.3029.33 beta (64-bit)

Self signed certs are accepted by Safari, this is only a problem with Chrome

### Update

As of Chrome v58.0.3029.41 beta, I get this helpful error message in the developer tools:

```
Subject Alternative Name Missing
The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative 
Name extension containing a domain name or IP address.
```

Comment: Are you asking if chrome is ratcheting up security and doubling down on trust? Or how to get better carts like using certbot or other sources?

Comment: No, I'm just wondering why my certs stopped working all of a sudden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily disable the SAN enforcement using the EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors policy, see [this page](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors) for details. This will allow you to reissue your certificates when time allows it.

On OSX this can be achieved using the following command:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors -bool true
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the missing Subject Alternative Name (SAN), which was not being filled in when I generated my self signed certs using openssl.  However, [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl) explains how to generate compatible certs using open ssl.

To check if your cert contains an SAN, use `openssl x509 -in my.crt -text`